# How to modify the string after parse in an xml file?

Tags: python, xml

I'm new to python and I want to learn python language. I had trouble finding a solution for modifying string after parsed in an xml file.

**This is the sample xml file:**

```
<Celeb>
  <artist>
    <name>Sammy Jellin</name>
    <age>27</age>
    <bday>01/22/1990</bday>
    <country>English</country>
    <sign>Virgo</sign>
  </artist>
</Celeb>
```

**Here is the code:**

```
def edit_f():
# Get the 3rd attribute 
    root = ET.parse('test_file/test_file.xml').getroot()
    subroot = root.getchildren()
    listchild = subroot.getchildren()[2].text
    print(listchild)

# Update the string for the <bday>
    replaceStr = listchild.replace('01/22/1990', '01/22/1992')

def main():
    edit_f()
```

**End**

How can I update the date?  I also tried using the datetime() but no good.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I added working code for your example with comments.

```
def edit_f():
    tree = ET.parse('test_file/test_file.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    bdays = root.findall('.//artist/bday')  # note: multiple elements
    bday = bdays[0]  # assuming there is only one artist/bday element
    bday.text = '01/22/1992'  # or ever any string you need
    tree.write('test_file/test_file.xml')  # with edited bday
```

You don't need `datetime` here, just assign any string you want to `bday.text`

**N.B.** `tree.write()` will rewrite your source file, and you cannot undo that. This is much safer to write the output to an another file.

Comment: Hi Nikolay Prokopyev,  
Thank you for your help.  I still have one more question.  How can I apply the update "bday.text = '01/22/1992'' to the file?  Currently, it's only print out to the python shell. And I want to update the change in the xml file.

Comment: I answered you by editing my answer. You need create a separate `tree` object before creating `root` object, and then just call `write`. Check NB comment also.